# Why do I get a Pioneer badge for following and then unfollowing an Area51 proposal?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, area-51

I clicked on Engineering's "Follow" button, did not check the verification e-mail, and promptly unfollowed it. Yet I still got the "[Pioneer](https://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/205/pioneer?userid=103388)" badge. Why?

Don't think I deserve a badge for that (although I'm looking forward to the launch of the site).

Comment: @bluet - not a dupe, since I did not fulfill the criterion of verifying the action through my e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no email verification requirement for the badge.

Following a proposal isn't exactly a hard thing to do and the badge's goal is just to introduce the feature in the first place. Now you know you can follow a proposal! This is working as intended.